# Code Analysis tool for legacy C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unix, code-analysis, legacy

looking for a code analysis tool for some legacy c/c++ code on unix
specifically to identify dependencies to

- specific functions
- specific (include?) files
- File/Socket I/O calls etc.
- function dependency tree from a root etc.

Comment: An awful lot of that could be solved very quickly with grep.

Comment: See our Source Code Search Engine, providing a "grep"-like code query language with a GUI, that makes it easy to pose "where is <this construct>" questions while avoiding problems with formatting. http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Doxygen` is probably what you're looking for. It can provide cross-reference, call graphs and dependency trees without programmer's markups, that seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There is [CodeViz: A CallGraph Visualizer](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/). It uses [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate nice big graphics.

Answer (score 1):

I have used successfully [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) in the past. It's not free but it comes with a trial period so you could make an opinion about it.

Comment: Tried it and it crashed on a reasonably large code base for which I wanted to get an overview. Sadly it didn't even save intermediate results ... :-|

Comment: Same, Understand is very promising but still unstable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LLVM infrastructure for some code analysis (e.g., building dependency graphs, searching for certain patterns, etc.), alongside with Clang or llvm-gcc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as function trees, etc. `doxygen` comes to mind.  See Ben Voigt's comment below.

If you're just trying to generally debug, in Linux `gdb` and `valgrind` are invaluable for figuring out what's going on at a low level.  In Windows `Visual Studio` offers a lot of similar debugging functionality.

Your question is a bit vague.  Can you tell us a bit more about the code and your assignment?

Comment: You can get `doxygen` to analyze everything, even without markup in the source, by setting `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`.

Comment: when it comes to scripting the debugger, I think WinDbg is more on par with `gdb`. But ultimately it's a matter of taste, I guess.